# Moshi HashMap deserializer

Tags: android, moshi

I don't know if it is possible to deserialise arrays into hashMap i have got json :

```
"additionalProperties": [
{
  "$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.AdditionalProperties, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
  "category": "Description",
  "key": "TerminalName",
  "sourceSystemKey": "BikePoints",
  "value": "200017",
  "modified": "2016-05-19T12:02:39.82"
}
........
]
```

and for that json i have got list :

```
private List<AdditionalProperties> additionalProperties;
```

everything works perfect but how store that json in HashMap where Key is "key" (TerminalName)"

```
private HashMap<String,AdditionalProperties> additionalProperties;
```

Comment: So that first object in the JSON array for `additionalProperties` is one `AdditionalProperties` object? And you want to pull out the String for `key` and make that the key for the whole object in your `Map`? If that's the case the simplest way would probably be to create an intermediate object and transform that with with `@ToJson` and `@FromJson` annotated methods. Have a look at https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/README.md#another-example

Answer (score 26):

Moshi supports fields declared as `Map` but not as `HashMap`. This way Moshi can use a different implementation of `Map` that’s more appropriate than `HashMap` for decoded JSON. If you change your field’s type to `Map<String,AdditionalProperties>` it should work.

Comment: This answer should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: You literally save my day. I was about to write a custom adapter just to handle HashMap. replacing with Map solve the issue