# How to serialize an Object to Map by Moshi

Tags: moshi

I want to serialize an Object to Map by Moshi.Here is my codes by Gson

```
    public static Map<String, String> toMap(Object obj, Gson gson) {
    if (gson == null) {
        gson = new Gson();
    }
    String json = gson.toJson(obj);
    Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {
    }.getType());
    return map;
}
```

And how to write by Moshi ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47114344/moshi-in-android-kotlin-enum-as-mutablemap-key-being-converted-to-string-when/47114650#47114650

Answer (score 11):

Here's one way. Check out the [toJsonValue doc here.](https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/4ac0d6f5efe52c70821ea7a8904d1d3c6d041d61/moshi/src/main/java/com/squareup/moshi/JsonAdapter.java#L70)

```
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder().build();

JsonAdapter<Object> adapter = moshi.adapter(Object.class);

Object jsonStructure = adapter.toJsonValue(obj);
Map<String, Object> jsonObject = (Map<String, Object>) jsonStructure;
```

If you know the type of `obj`, it'd be better to look up the adapter of that type, rather than of Object. (The Object JsonAdadpter has to look up the runtime type on every `toJson` call.

Comment: Works fine. I will apply your solution.

Comment: @NanoJava8 you should mark this answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 7):

@NanoJava8 solution crashes but can be made to work with a minor change using `Map` instead of `HashMap`

```
Type type = Types.newParameterizedType(Map.class, String.class, String.class);

JsonAdapter<Map<String,String>> adapter = moshi.adapter(type);

Map<String,String> map = adapter.fromJson(json);
```

As stated by [Jesse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43822327/4646227) in the answer Moshi support fields as  `Map` but not `HashMap`.

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin:

```
val type = Types.newParameterizedType(
            MutableMap::class.java,
            String::class.java,
            String::class.java
        )
        val adapter: JsonAdapter<Map<String, String>> = moshi.adapter(type)
        val map: Map<String, String> = adapter.fromJson(responseJson)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Type type = Types.newParameterizedType(HashMap.class, String.class, String.class);

JsonAdapter<Map<String,String>> adapter = moshi.adapter(type);

Map<String,String> map = adapter.fromJson(json);
```

Comment: Moshi should crash here, preventing you from creating a JsonAdapter for a platform HashMap. If it doesn't, please let me know!

Comment: Yeah, this correctly fails with an IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: It doesn't crash

Comment: @EricCochran It doesn't crash and works as i expect. Version 1.5.0

Comment: Unless you are registering a JsonAdapter for HashMap, you will get: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Platform java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> annotated [] requires explicit JsonAdapter to be registered`.
Moshi doesn't allow you to hurt yourself by relying on the implementation of platform types.

Answer (score 1):

```
class HashMapJsonAdapter<K, V>(
  private val keyAdapter: JsonAdapter<K>,
  private val valueAdapter: JsonAdapter<V>
) : JsonAdapter<HashMap<K, V>>() {

  @Throws(IOException::class)
  override fun toJson(writer: JsonWriter, map: HashMap<K, V>?) {
    writer.beginObject()
    for ((key, value) in map ?: emptyMap<K, V>()) {
      if (key == null) {
        throw JsonDataException("Map key is null at ${writer.path}")
      }
    keyAdapter.toJson(writer, key)
    valueAdapter.toJson(writer, value)
    }
    writer.endObject()
  }

  @Throws(IOException::class)
  override fun fromJson(reader: JsonReader): HashMap<K, V>? {
    val result = linkedMapOf<K, V>()
    reader.beginObject()
    while (reader.hasNext()) {
      val name = keyAdapter.fromJson(reader)
      val value = valueAdapter.fromJson(reader)
      val replaced = result.put(name!!, value!!)
      if (replaced != null) {
        throw JsonDataException("Map key '$name' has multiple values at path ${reader.path} : $replaced and value")
      }
    }
    reader.endObject()
    return result
  }

  override fun toString(): String = "JsonAdapter($keyAdapter=$valueAdapter)"

  companion object
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to fix: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expected at least one `@ToJson` or `@FromJson` method on ...HashMapJsonAdapter