# Moshi in Android Kotlin - ENUM as MutableMap key being converted to String when deseralized

Tags: android, kotlin, moshi

I have a `MutableMap<CryptoTypes, CurrentTradingInfo>` that I'm wanting to save in `onSaveInstanceState` and was going to use Moshi to convert back and forth.  `CryptoTypes is an ENUM`

```
private var tickerData: MutableMap<CryptoTypes, CurrentTradingInfo> = mutableMapOf()


fun convertTickerDataJson(): String {
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
    val jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter<MutableMap<CryptoTypes, CurrentTradingInfo>>(MutableMap::class.java)
    return jsonAdapter.toJson(tickerData)
}

fun restoreTickerDataFromJson(data: String) {
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
    val jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter<MutableMap<CryptoTypes, CurrentTradingInfo>>(MutableMap::class.java)
    tickerData = jsonAdapter.fromJson(data)
}
```

The data is serializing correctly, but when it's deserialized, it's giving me back a `MutableMap<String, CurrentTradingInfo>` instead?

When I look at my tickerData map in studio before I serialize it, it's clearly storing the ENUM as an ENUM

[image]

This is the map after being deserialized back [note the map is unordered and I had to re-run it again, hence the map keys in different orders]

[image]

How is it able to give me back an incorrectly typed map?  Am I doing something wrong?

When I try to access the map post conversion it crashes with the below since the type is wrong

```
Java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.nebulights.crytpotracker.CryptoTypes
```

If I create two variables

```
   private var tickerDataA: MutableMap<CryptoTypes, CurrentTradingInfo> = mutableMapOf()

   private var tickerDataB: MutableMap<String, CurrentTradingInfo> = mutableMapOf()
```

I can't go `tickerDataA = tickerDataB`, it shows as a type mismatch and won't let me compile as it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
moshi.adapter<MutableMap<CryptoTypes, CurrentTradingInfo>>(MutableMap::class.java)
```

The problem occurs because you are not providing the complete type, only the generic `MutableMap` class. Because of this it uses the `Object` serializer instead of one specialized for the key/value types.

Try creating a parameterized type:

```
val type = Types.newParameterizedType(MutableMap::class.java, CryptoTypes::class.java, CurrentTradingInfo::class.java)
val jsonAdapter = moshi.adapter<MutableMap<CryptoTypes, CurrentTradingInfo>>(type)
```

This should provide Moshi with the information it required to correctly serialize the map.

Comment: That solved it, thank you!  So does that mean Moshi was returning Map<Object, Object> and that's why it was able to assign it to my typed map?  I'm surprised it simply didn't just crash at the assignment line with a type mismatch?

Comment: You need to remember that type arguments tend to disappear during runtime, any crashes would have to happen during runtime while calling `get()` or something.