# Retrofit Moshi Unable to create @Body converter for java.util.HashMap

Tags: android, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines, moshi

The line `EarthlingsApi.retrofitService.register(params)`

in my code below

```
fun clickLogin(){
    val params = HashMap<String, String>()
    params["email"] = email
    params["idToken"] = idToken
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val userRegisterResult = EarthlingsApi.retrofitService.register(params)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.d("exception? " + e.toString())
            _response.value = "Failure: ${e.message}"
        }
    }
}
```

will always return the error `exception? java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create @Body converter for java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String, java.lang.String> (parameter #1) for method ApiService.register`

And below is the code for `EarthlingsApi`

```
private val moshi = Moshi.Builder()
    .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
    .build()
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .build()

interface ApiService {
    @POST("/user/register")
    suspend fun register(@Body params: HashMap<String, String>?): UserRegister?
}

object EarthlingsApi {
    val retrofitService : ApiService by lazy {retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java) }
}
```

Previously I use Gson and never faced this error. Is there anything else I should do when using Moshi?

Answer (score 2):

It seems Moshi supports fields declared as Map but not as HashMap. So just change the `HashMap` inside `suspend fun register(@Body params: HashMap<String, String>?): UserRegister?` to `Map` and it will work. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43822327/301584) helped me in solving this, but unfortunately, the questioner there doesn't mark it as an answer. So maybe anyone later who bumped into this same issue can upvote the answer there.